# How do I deploy apps to an Android phone using Android Studio on a Chromebook?

Tags: android-studio, chromebook

I'm using Android Studio on a Dell Chromebook. I've confirmed that the adb daemon is running, but when I plug in my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S10e) it is not recognized by adb. Instead, I get a Chrome OS notification saying "USB device detected" and giving me the option to "Connect to Linux" but when I click that button nothing happens. On my phone I get a dialog saying "Allow access to your data" but when I click allow it just opens a file browser on the Chromebook.

When I plug this same phone into my Windows laptop and iMac, I get a different dialog on my phone saying "Allow USB debugging" and then I am able to run apps from Android Studio on the device. So it seems like the problem is with my Chromebook, but I can't find any documentation for my problem. According to this page there should be no additional configuration required on Chrome OS:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?utm_source=android-studio#resolve-usb-issues

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is anyone able to connect to their Android phone from their Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your device's setting, the about this phone, software information then click 7 times, VERY FAST, on the build model. It will create a new folder named "Developer options" on the bottom of the page. Go there and click depuration through USB.
 This should work.
 Try this link for more information https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/activate-developer-options-your-galaxy-s10-0194524/